# If child type is type of parent

Tags: c#, .net, types

I am trying to pass a an inherited class type in to a method and want to check if the type is a type of base class. How can I do this, since inherited.GetType() == typeof(baseclass) will return false?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) operator does this.

```
if (inherited is baseclass)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

You could also use `Type.BaseType` if you want to know that it is exactly the direct parent.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [`Type.IsSubclassOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
inherited.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base));
```

Comment: Although it is not explicitly indicated in documentation, this returns true even for the types that are grandchildren or deeper inheriting..

Answer (score 3):

Use [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (typeof(baseclass).IsAssignableFrom(inh.GetType())
{
...
}
```